# Multi variable integral with probability density function of random variable

Tags: integration, random-variables, density-function

I'm not good at multi variable integration. So, I am stuck at this part of research paper.

How the $p_{ij} - p_{ji}$ can be like the form of $rX(i)X(j)E[p_j-p_i]$?

> [image]